# Mockito not matching arguments when stubbed with functional interface

Tags: java, lambda, mockito, junit5

I am having trouble mocking a service dependency that accepts a functional interface in a method. I have simplified the problem to the follow test application. Mockito is not matching on the passed in lambda method reference. I have tried various ways of passing in a reference to the stubbing.

```
package com.example.test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.function.Function;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@FunctionalInterface
interface MyCallback<T> extends Function<String, T> {
    T apply(String s);
}

interface MyDependency {
    <T> T submit(String id, MyCallback<T> myCallback);
}


class MyService {
    private final MyDependency myDependency;

    MyService(MyDependency myDependency) {
        this.myDependency = myDependency;
    }

    String run() {
        MyCallback<String> myCallback = getStringMyCallback();
        return myDependency.submit("myId", myCallback);
    }

    public MyCallback<String> getStringMyCallback() {
        return s -> "hello " + s;
    }
}


@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestUtil {

    @Mock
    private MyDependency myDependency;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void test() {
        MyCallback<String> myCallback = myService.getStringMyCallback();
        when(myDependency.submit("id", myCallback)).thenReturn("world");
        String value = myService.run();
        assertThat(value).isEqualTo("world");
    }


}
```

The desired outcome is to pass a method lambda to the myDependency and stub different results. In this code the contents of 'value' is null.

Comment: `getStringMyCallback()` returns a new object each time it's called, I think that's why it doesn't match.

Comment: And "id" doesn't match "myId"!